# loop in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create query that will include calculated attributes distinguished by years. Starting from year 2007 to current year. Simplified example of what my sql looks like:

```
SELECT users.id as id
       users.name as name
       SUM(CASE WHEN posts.approved = 1) AND posts.created_at BETWEEN '2007-01-01 00:00:00 +0100' AND '2007-12-31 23:59:59 +0100' THEN posts.ratings ELSE 0 END) as approved_rating_2007
       SUM(CASE WHEN posts.approved = 0) AND posts.created_at BETWEEN '2007-01-01 00:00:00 +0100' AND '2007-12-31 23:59:59 +0100' THEN posts.ratings ELSE 0 END) as rejected_rating_2007
       SUM(CASE WHEN posts.approved = 1) AND posts.created_at BETWEEN '2008-01-01 00:00:00 +0100' AND '2008-12-31 23:59:59 +0100' THEN posts.ratings ELSE 0 END) as approved_rating_2008
       SUM(CASE WHEN posts.approved = 0) AND posts.created_at BETWEEN '2008-01-01 00:00:00 +0100' AND '2008-12-31 23:59:59 +0100' THEN posts.ratings ELSE 0 END) as rejected_rating_2008
       etc...
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
```

Is there a way to write it in some kind of loop that would always include records from 2007 to current_year?

Comment: fix your syntax, your case when constructions are invalid

Comment: you can check like this "posts.created_at BETWEEN YEAR('2007') AND YEAR(NOW())"

Comment: Should be `LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id,
      u.name,
      year(p.created_at) as create_year
      SUM(CASE WHEN p.approved = 1 then p.ratings else 0 end) as approved_rating,
      SUM(CASE WHEN p.approved = 0 then p.ratings else 0 end) as rejected_rating
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts p ON p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.name, create_year
```

Comment: I need to change some of my code to work with it but is't nice solution - thanks @juergen